# Copy kirby site using git

Tags: html, git, copy, kirby

- My friend create a site using Kirby, I was asked to add the content to a git repository and to deploy the content in a server..

I've created the git repository and I've added all the content using git add -A ... i've committed and pushed the content ... however when I clone the repository in the server,  the site do not work correctly!

For example I've got the index.html page but any of the redirections (toward other html page belonging to the site) is not working .. any Ideas ?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using relative urls to the other html pages?

Comment: the redirections are well written (relative url) ... but it is like only the index page can be displayed ...

Comment: I've resolved the problem by copying the file .htaccess of another site already existing in the server !! is this the solution ?

Comment: adding a working htaccess file might well be the answer

Comment: but why the local htaccess is not working on the server ? and is it correct to use a htaccess file of another site in my site ?

Comment: have you looked at http://getkirby.com/support#links

Comment: thanks, yess, I've copied the .htaccess of my friend on the server but it is not working ... the only manner is to use the htaccess that is existing in the server it self !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is resolved by copying the file .htaccess of another site already existing in the server !!

This is a tormented solution !! is this the only thing I may do?

Answer (score 0):

the .htaccess is mandatory for the pretty urls to work

> The .htaccess file, which is needed to generate nice URLs is such an invisible file. So we need to make sure to copy that as well.

You have to disable the url rewriting in `site/config/config.php`